# babel-runtime will not work on instance methods

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-polyfill

I understand the difference between babel-runtime and babel-polyfill that the first one doesn't populate global scope while latter does. I think babel-runtime is safer hovewer I can't understand what this means and how does it effects me:

> NOTE: Instance methods such as "foobar".includes("foo") will not work since that would require modification of existing built-ins (Use babel-polyfill for that).

As far as I understand instance methods are like `map, filter, reduce` because they are called on existing object. Which example of this won't get polified by babel-runtime? :

```
//1
['aa', 'bb', 'cc'].forEach(console.log);

//2
const arr = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'];
arr.forEach(console.log);

//3
const entries = Object.entries(someObj).filter(([key, value]) => key.startsWith('hello'));

//4
const map = new Map();

//5
var s = new Set(["foo", window]);
Array.from(s);
```

How can I exactly identify instance methods?

I replaced babel-polyfill in my project for babel-runtime as it supposed to be better, but now I'm not sure what is safe to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://abdulapopoola.com/2013/03/30/static-and-instance-methods-in-javascript/) a link which explains static methods vs instance methods in Javascript.

Basically:

```
class SomeClass {
   instancMethod() {
    return 'Instance method has been called';
   }

   static staticMethod() {
     return 'Static method has been called';
   }
}
// Invoking a static method
SomeClass.staticMethod(); // Called on the class itself
// Invoking an instance method 
var obj = new SomeClass();
obj.instanceMethod(); // Called on an instance of the class
```

the equivalent in ES5 is something like:

```
function SomeClass() {
   this.prototype.instanceMethod = function() {
      return 'Instance method has been called';
   }
}
SomeClass.staticMethod = function() {
   return 'Static method has been called';
}
// And the invocations:
SomeClass.staticMethod();
new SomeClass().instanceMethod();
```

When you're using babel-polyfill in IE11 for example, all the ES2015+ methods which are not present are defined, methods such as Array.from (static method) or String.prototype.repeat (instance method). This is polluting the global state like you say, but instance methods like like:

```
myInstanceObj.repeat(4)
```

will work, if the type of myInstanceObj has the repeat method. If at runtime myInstanceObj is a string and you included the babel-polyfill, then great. But if you're using the babel-runtime knowing the type of the myInstanceObj type at transpile time (when babel transforms your code, in order to know how to transform, and what method to call instead of the method repeat) is sometimes tricky/not possible, that is why instance methods such as the one above are sometimes hard to transform by the babel-runtime && transform-runtime plugin.

On the other hand code like:

```
Array.from([1, 2, 3], x => x + x);
```

is really easy to transform, we know at transpile time that Array.from is the method from from the object Array, so instead of it, in IE11 we will use whatever....put code here...

If we're using babel-polyfill, this method is there already, since the global scope has been polluted to add this method, so all good again. It all depends of what you need.

Comment: Then it seems it’s always safer to use polyfill because runtime will work in one case and not in other. Still confused why risk using Babel-runtime when it may fail. Thanks for detailed answer anyway.

Comment: In our very old app made to work with IE9, there are a lot of JavaServerFaces richfaces components (quite old stuff) they are patched and hacked (with js) in multiple places to work with this old browser. If you now come and include babel-polyfill, some of these JSF components WILL BREAK because the polyfill patches many, many(many) things. Therefore it is not acceptable to use babel-polyfill in this case, but it's acceptable to use babel-runtime, because that would not break our old JSF components, but you're right, this might fail in cases. Feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful :)